# originally Creation Date of a Document

Tags: asp.net, datetime, document, creation

i have a file with documents.

i wrote a applikation with asp.net.

i need to read the creation date and the date of the last change (and title, etc.)
for that i used the API filesysteminfo.

in the file are documents, that are a copy of a vss server.
but when a document is copied, the date of creation changes to the "date of copy".
but i need the original date of creation.

any idea?

greetings

Comment: for eyample @.doc there are two date of creations stored, the originall and the "new" with filesysteminfo i can't reach the originall stored in the .doc

is there a way to get it? AND is there a way to get .pdf and .txt originall dates either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem with robocopy

robocopy source destination  [parameter]

default it copies Data, Attributes and **Timestamp**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28WS.10%29.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displayLang=en

Answer (score 0):

If the file has been overwritten, you will not be able to get the creation date that is stored in SourceSafe.

You may have more luck using the [SourceSafe API](http://mark.michaelis.net/SourceSafe/Faq.htm#_Toc33748946), however this uses OLE automation, so may not be very simple.

Comment: i just copy the document.
then this copy is in my file.
BUT then the "new date of creation" is the date when the "copy is created"

Comment: it's not overwritten,
i want to keep the original date in the document, when i copy it, and to read this date from the document in the new file

Comment: You say "read this date from the document" - how is it stored in the document? How do you manually view it?

Comment: hm, ok, 
it is normally stored on my computer (later on a server), right mouse click, then the last point "propeties" ?  

vss document --> copy to my pc
document on my pc has a new creation date ( maybe because it's new?)
i want to read from the doc from my pc the date, but the original date, nut this new one..

i hope i explained some how ok :>

Comment: VSS overwrites the old file when you get latest, so it now has a new created date. You can't get the created date of the document that was replaced. You will have to query VSS directly to get that information (see the link and read the linked articles in it for details).

Comment: i dont replace an artikel, i just copy an document into a folder which is empty.
when i take a look @ the creation date in this folder it's the date when i put the document from vss into this folder.

2009 i create a doc in vss.
2010 i put this doc into a folder on the server

the doc has been created 2009,
but when i look @ the folder on the server, it says 2010, but it should say 2009 :>

Comment: sorry i didn't explained it good at the beginning,

when i copy a document, the creationtime ist set to the time when i copy the document.

when i copy a document from C:  to D: then has the doc. in D: an other creation time ( the time when i did copy it)

Comment: The creation date refers to the date the file was created on disk (so, if you copy to another drive/folder, the date would be the date it was copied). This is how windows works.

Comment: ah okay,
is there some kind of workaround? :>

or what should i do? :>